# Firestore only allow modification of field if user not contained in array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document like

```
Field Score: number
Field usersThatRated: array
```

How can I enforce in the firestore rules that only users whose id is NOT included in the `usersthatRated` array are allowed to increment/decrement the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following security rules:

```
match /collection/{docId} {
  allow read, write: if (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['usersThatRead']) && 
    !(request.auth.uid in resource.data.usersThatRead));
}
```

The [`hasAny`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) is just to check if `usersThatRead` field is being updated. If yes, then check if user's UID is already present in that array or not.

[`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) operator is used to check if a value is present in given array.